# Call C# method on button click using JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

I am trying to call a C# function on a button click using JavaScript/jQuery function.

I went through similar issues and their solutions, but none fits this case. My C# function does not return anything. It's a function that triggers a job from the task scheduler. Is there a different way to write the JavaScript function, where the function does not return anything?

Below is the code.

HTML:

```
<button id="btnClick" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true">Replay</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".btnClick").on('click', function() {
    $.ajax({
      async: true,
      url: "Home/ABVReplay",
      cache: false,
    });
    console.log("Replayed!");
  });
});
```

C#:

```
[WebMethod]
public void ABVReplay()
{
    using (TaskService tasksrvc = new TaskService("<server.name>", "<username>", "<domain>", "<password>"))
    {
        Task task = tasksrvc.FindTask("<taskName>");
        task.Run();
    }

}
```

The job runs if I just use the C# code in a console application. So, there is no connection/login issue as such.

Console app code:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Win32.TaskScheduler;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (TaskService tasksrvc = new TaskService("<server.name>", "<username>", "<domain>", "<password>"))
        {
            Task task = tasksrvc.FindTask("<taskName>");
            task.Run();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's your webservice url?

Comment: Sorry, just edited the url. Home is the Controller and ABVReplay is the function.

Comment: @D-Shih I tried your suggestion, still didn't work and yes, the url is correct.

Comment: Please use the Chrome Developer Tools to show us the Request Headers and Response Headers for the AJAX request.

Comment: Could the program executed in the webserver by the URL when you call by browse URL?

Comment: Is `Replayed!` being written to the console in Chrome Developer Tools?

Comment: No, it does not show replayed in the console. I've inserted breakpoints as well in the c# code but on button click it does not even go to the breakpoint.

Comment: Well then there is no point worrying about why the ajax request isn't working. **If the console log is not occurring then your click event handler code isn't running at all**. Please run the web page and do View Source from the web browser. Find the part of the HTML where the `Replay` button is and copy and paste that into your question.

Comment: @mjwills thanks for tha! did some console logging and found that click event was not running but now the click event is working fine. I click the button and it gives me this error: 

     http://localhost:57114/Home/Home/ABVReplay?_=1532094788463 404 not found

The url should be http://localhost:57114/Home/ABVReplay?_=1532094788463 but somehow it is showing Home twice in the ajax call. Any idea on how to rectify this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.` represents `jquery class` and `#` represents `id`, you have to replace for this code, and should works.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#btnClick").on('click', function () {

    $.ajax({
        async: true,
        url: "Home/ABVReplay",
        cache: false,
     });
    console.log("Replayed!");
  });
});
```

Comment: also, try with : `url: "/Home/ABVReplay",`
What message do you get in your browser console? after click the button?

Answer (score 4):

Your jquery selector need to change

```
$("#btnClick")
```

instead of

```
$(".btnClick")
```

and make sure your call URL is correct.

`#` select html tag `id`

`.` select html tag `class`